# Why is `gnus-group-prepared-hook` never called?

Tags: hooks, gnus

I'm wondering why this hook never works:

```
(add-hook 'gnus-group-prepared-hook 'gnus-group-list-all-groups)
```

Description of the hook:

> is called as the very last thing after the group buffer has been generated. It may be used to move point around, for instance.

I've also tried `gnus-group-mode-hook` (specified function is called, but no effect) and `gnus-group-prepare-hook` (never called).

Expected behavior: when I start Gnus via <kbd>M-x gnus</kbd>, it should list all groups immediately.

Comment: The tag you're looking for is called `hooks`, and it already exists :)

Comment: I don't get the same behavior on my Emacs when I try this.  (For one, you have a typo with `gnus-group-prepared-hook`.  More significantly, my Gnus does list all groups, but only after erroring due to max recursion depth.)  Please post a minimum working example for me to debug the problem ... I should be able to start emacs with `emacs -Q`, eval your code in the \*scratch* buffer, and see what you're talking about.

Comment: @purple_arrows, sorry I don't see any typo in `gnus-group-prepared-hook`.

Comment: @purple_arrows, Minimal complete example is not easy to write, aside from contents of `.emacs` that you can evaluate in `*scratch*`, it should include `.gnus` file and `.authinfo`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still unable to make `gnus-group-prepared-hook` work. Empty groups are not displayed on start of Gnus and I don't get any error messages.

However, I have succeeded in my initial intention to display all groups automatically. In order to achieve this behavior, one should set value of variable `gnus-permanently-visible-groups`.

Description of this variable:

> Groups matching this regexp will always be listed in the group buffer, whether they are empty or not.

So, if you want to display all groups on start of Gnus, add this line to your `.emacs`:

```
(setq gnus-permanently-visible-groups "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in the question.

> is called as the very last thing after the group buffer has been generated.

Meanwhile, `gnus-group-list-all-groups` essentially regenerates the group buffer. This means that the hook will be called again when `gnus-group-list-all-groups` is about to finish. But `gnus-group-list-all-groups` is contained in the hook, so it will run again and again and again...

Eventually, Emacs throws a max-lisp-depth error (which you should find somewhere in your Messages buffer) and the function quits.

Comment: It's the case with `gnus-group-prepare-hook`. However, `gnus-group-prepared-hook` is never called at all, even if I write `(add-hook 'gnus-group-prepared-hook (lambda () (message "hi!")))`, it doesn't work. P.S. [`gnus-group-prepared-hook` exists](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Misc-Group-Stuff.html), it's not a typo. Click the link to read about difference between `prepare` and `prepared` hook. My question was about the second one.